# Azure AD. Authentication and authorization against multiple scopes. How to do it silently?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, token

I am trying to do authentication for a windows desktop app with Flutter. And having a six scopes for six services (five mine and a Graph), I make my user to login six times to get six different authorization codes.

I've registered my app with AAD and added scopes for five services of mine and also a scope for Graph service:

```
https://my.cool.service1/user_impersonation...https://my.cool.service5/user_impersonation  https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
```

First I make an url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={https://localhost/9081}&response_mode=query&scope={takeAnyScopeYouLike}&code_challenge={codeChallengeCode}&code_challenge_method=S256
```

Then my app launches default browser with this url, a user inputs login and password, then redirect url is called and there is my app's http server which listens to a response and parses it to get an authorization code, which will be used late to get an access token. Now I want to get an authorization code for another scope, I need access tokens for all my services. And got no idea how to do it silently because repeating this process for all of six scopes will make my user to do a login-password job six times, which is obviously bad. I **cannot pass all my scopes to login endpoint at once** and I **cannot use one authorization_code for all scopes** for it determined only for one scope. Can anybody advise me how to get access tokens without user interaction save first time?

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

You can make use of [**On-Behalf-Of**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) flow to call the APIs using one access token like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms 
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ClientID/test.read
&state=12345
```

The **auth-code** generated successfully:

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://ClientID/test.read
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

By using the above generated access token, **I tried to call API2** like below:

```json
scope:api://App2ClientID/access_as_user
```

[image]

By using the same access token, **I am able to call Microsoft Graph API** too:

```json
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
```

[image]